# JavaScript: Sort array of objects based on a particular property of the objects in a specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects containing a particular structure. Then, I have an array (given by the user), which contains values in the order which the elements should be sorted. For simplicity, I'll give the following example:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
{objectId: 1, color: 'Orange'},
{objectId: 2, color: 'Blue'},
{objectId: 3, color: 'White'},...
]
```

And the array given by the user for sorting:

```
['White', 'Orange', 'Blue']
```

Now my question is, how can I sort the first array, so that all objects with color white come first, then all the elements with orange color and then blue?

*Note: The array will be given by the user, so cannot sort alphabetically.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: No, that question is based on sorting the properties alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a little trial and error on my part resulted in the following code:

```
const sortedArray = arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => {
  return colors.findIndex(c => c === a.myColor) - colors.findIndex(c => c === b.myColor)
})
// colors being the array given by the user.
```